# How to able/start a pm2 module without restarting my pc or reinstall this module?

Tags: node.js, pm2, pm2-logrotate

If I killed the pm2 module, just like pm2-logrotate, how do I start this module without restarting my pc or reinstall this module.

Comment: how did you killed the pm2-logrotate module?

Comment: pm2 delete {mode's id}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-initialize PM2 via:

`pm2 update`